# Need some help rendering JSON in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have resource questions and user, I have to give an opportunity for user to upvote or downvote question. I made a relationship has_many through votes for user and question. Also I set Vote. I'm a nuber in web-dev so I've this is what I've set smth like this:

```
-if current_user.votes_on_questions.include? @question
  -if @question.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first.vote_field == true
    = form_for @question.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first, method: :patch do |f|
      = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
      = f.hidden_field :votable_id, value: @question.id
      = f.hidden_field :votable_type, value: 'Question'
      = f.hidden_field :vote_field, value: false
      = f.submit 'Vote +', class: 'upvote-submit'
  -elsif @question.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first.vote_field == false
    = form_for @question.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first, method: :patch do |f|
      = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
      = f.hidden_field :votable_id, value: @question.id
      = f.hidden_field :votable_type, value: 'Question'
      = f.hidden_field :vote_field, value: true
      = f.submit 'Vote -', class: 'upvote-submit'
-else
  div.voting_dom
    = render 'votes/vote', question: @question
```

Looks terrible hah? Dont forget - I'm a complete nuber. 
Simple js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.new_vote').bind("ajax:success", function(e, data, stauts, xhr){    
    $('.voting_dom').replaceWith(xhr.responseText);
  });
});
```

And start of controller

```
def create
  @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @vote.save
    format.json{ render json: @vote }
  else
    format.json{ render json: @vote.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I've stuck on how to how to set a json response. Would be very grateful for any commet or advice

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only trying to render json, I would forgo using `respond_to`.

try something like:

```
if @vote.save
 render json: @vote 
else
  render json: @vote.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity 
end
```

Comment: Ok!!! My problem now is that I have to render form with recieved @vote. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking? Do you mean you want to change the page based on the ajax response? What do you want to do with the form?

Comment: ))) In my case vote partial is a form. Im not so good english speaker, sorry about that. I have 3 options First one - user haven't voted yet, so there should be a 2 forms(one for upvote another for downvote) with url to vote#create. It should response with json, it would be esear to respond with ajaj (as for me), still the task is to send back json. So now the page should render only one  form, that should have url to vote#update. I've made some tryouts myself but I am a  newcommer here, could you please tell me where should I post to show you. Update my header post?

Comment: Update your original question with more details if you can.